# Google Cloud Free Tier - Setting up alerts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a small VPS to run some fun twitter bots from, but I'm having issues understanding the pricing structure to prevent myself from being charged.

My understanding is that I have access to 720/744 hours of an f1-micro instance every month, with 1GB Egress free per month, and that anything over that amount will cost extra.
The instance hours is simple if I only run one, but I'm struggling to figure out how to properly monitor the egress.

I've tried going into monitoring and setting up an alert, but I can't figure out how to set one up that alerts me when "950MB of egress has been used within the current period".

Would anyone be able to give me any advice here? I'd rather not get charged extra if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an alert on the egress but you can [set an alert on your budget](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets). If the egress explose and you start pay for it, you will receive an alert. You can set an alert to 1$ for example, you will be informed when you will start to pay (after the free tier and the free trial budget)

Comment: Damn, that's a little bit disappointing but I guess will have to do. I was hoping to be able to prevent charges entirely, rather than just step any potential bleeding.

Comment: No, it's a real concern (and strong request from the community to Google Cloud): there is no feature to block the billing, only to alert in case of overruns

Comment: That's a real shame, aside from this I've really liked what I've been poking around with. Thanks for the clarification though, much appreciated